# Can I create a super-class with a restricted generic type?

Tags: typescript1.4

I have the class:

```
export class LinkedList<t>
```

I presently create a super class using:

```
export class ListBody extends collections.LinkedList<Element>
```

And it all works great. However, I declare this class in several other classes and in each place, it actually only takes several super-classes of Element. So I would like in thos other places, instead of declaring:

```
this.body = new moduleListBody.ListBody();
```

declare:

```
this.body = new moduleListBody.ListBody<ElementOne | ElementTwo>();
```

Is there a way to do this? I can't skip past the ListBody class because I have a ton of code in it that operates on Element objects.

Update: example

```
export class Element {

}

export class LinkedList<t>  {

    public add(index : number, value : t);
    public add(index : number, collection : LinkedList<t>);
    public add(index : number, collection : t[]);
    add(index : number, arg : t | LinkedList<t> | t[]) {
    }
}

export class ListBody <T extends Element> extends LinkedList<T> {

    public fubar(): void {
        var element = new Element();
        this.add(0, element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible, the below code is an example of how you can accomplish something like this:

```ts
class LinkedList<T> {
    el: T
}

class ListBody<T extends Element> extends LinkedList<T> { }


var list = new ListBody<HTMLElement | SVGElement>();
```

`list.el` will be `HTMLElement | SVGElement`.

UPDATE: You would need to pass the type into fubar, or alternatively store the constructor for T on the extended classes. See below:

```ts
export class ListBody <T extends Element> extends LinkedList<T> {
    public fubar(Type: new () => T): void {
        var element = new Type();
        this.add(0, element);
    }
}
```

or

```ts
export class ListBody<T extends Element> extends LinkedList<T> {
    Type: new () => T;

    public fubar(): void {
        var element = new this.Type();
        this.add(0, element);
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I'm getting a compile error when I call methods on LinkedList to pass in Element objects - Element is not assignable to parameter of type T.

Comment: Interesting, could you post a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) with the relevant code. I can try to help you out!

Comment: Thank you. But I don't think this is worth the hit of the new call just to make my type checking a bit more strict. Too bad. I'm going to leave this question open in case one of the typescript team knows of a way without the new. Thank you.

Comment: I think the idea is if you were able to say `this.add(0, new Element())` then this would violate your definition of `ListBody<T extends Element> extends LinkedList<T>` since you can only ever be sure that any ListBody will have items of type Element in it.

Comment: You're right. I hadn't thought that through. Thanks.